# CakePHP Tree behavior -find specyfic level elements

Tags: sql, cakephp, nested-sets, cakephp-2.4

I just wondering how do fetch specific level elements from model with TreeBehavior.

It's pretty simply for first level elements.. just find elements with parent_id =>null but for deeper levels...?

Is there any clean and simply way to do that?

Comment: Do you know the parent of the elements you're trying to access? You should be able to access them with `parent_id => 7` (or whatever the id of the parent element is).

Comment: No I don't. I just want to display (for example) all second level elements and I don't know how many 1st level element exists in db and whats id's they are. Of course is possible to fetch all 1st level ids and then find all children for this ids. But this sounds bit complicated if we whant to fetch a very deep level elements

Comment: I don't think there's a way to identify what level an element is just from the tree. Best option I can think of is to add another field to the database that identifies the level, and then make sure you change that field whenever you edit the element.

Comment: You can pretty much do everything with nested set trees, but caching the level in the table itself might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in pure SQL. You can get even the count of descendant per node.

```
 SELECT n.name,
         COUNT(*)-1 AS level,
         ROUND ((n.rgt - n.lft - 1) / 2) AS offspring
    FROM tree AS n,
         tree AS p
   WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt
GROUP BY n.lft
ORDER BY n.lft;
```

If you add `HAVING level = 2` after `GROUP` the statement, it might get only the level you're looking for. Honestly I've been to lazy to test it right now and to turn it into a CakePHP find() array, give it a try.

This website http://www.klempert.de/nested_sets/ has a very good explanation of how to work with trees, but it is written in german, you can try to translate it via google translate.

Comment: I tested on my `groups` table and it seems to work. Just a note: is `rght` and not `rgt`

Comment: Hi, it work nice (as arilia wrote rght insted of rgt) but I can't figure out how to limit query result to single level. AND level = x return query exceptions "Unknown column 'level' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @hawlikus add `HAVING level = 2` after GROUP statement